# Find the point on a parameterized line closest to another line

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $x_1 = (1, 2, 3)$ and $x_2 = (3, 2, 1)$. Consider the two lines $x_1(s) = x_1 + su_1$ and $x_2(t) = x_2 + tu_2$.

$u_1 = (\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$,
$u_2 = (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0)$, and
$u_3 = (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{18}})$.

Find the point on the line parameterized by $x_1(s)$ that is closest to the line parameterized by $x_2(t)$, and find point on the line parameterized by $x_2(t)$ that is closest to the line parameterized by $x_1(t)$.

---

I've already calculated the magnitude squared of $[x_1(s) - x_2(t)]$

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to determine the value of $s,t$. An observation is suppose the point $P_1$ on line $l_1$, $P_2$ on line $l_2$ which gives the minimum distance, then $\vec{P_1P_2}$ must perpendicular to two tangent vector as $u_1 = (2,2,1), u_2 =(-1,1,0)$. Hence what you need to do is to take inner product with $u_1, u_2$, obtain two linear equations, solve for $t,s$ and then you get the points.

Following is a proof of the fact:

Let $P_1$ on line $l_1$ with tangent vector $u_1$, $P_2$ on line $l_2$ with tangent vector $u_2$ giving the minimum distance. Then $l_1$ can be written as $P_1+tu_1$,$l_2$ can be written as $P_2+su_2$.

Let $d(t,s)=|| (P_1+tu_1)-(P_2+su_2)||^2$. Then $(0,0)$ must be a local minimum of $d$. set$\nabla d(0,0)=\vec 0$, you get the result.